# SSRS multi tablix not allowing repeat of headers

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

So I have a dataset (a union for multiple tables [parts and labor]). This report is for multiple agencies/multiple invoices, Group by invoice and page breaking on invoice#.

Example

Tablix1

```
Row - Agency - repeatonnewpage, Keep with Group After
Row - Invoice- repeatonnewpage, Keep with Group After
Row - Date- repeatonnewpage, Keep with Group After

 Tablix2 (is filtered to the parts)
 Header Row 
 Detail Row - Item, Description   (can be multiple lines)

 Tablix3 (is filtered to labor)
 Header Row
 Detail Row - Item, Description  (can be multiple lines)
```

More detail rows

My problem is when Tablix 2 or 3 has so much data it pushes the report to a new page the Tablix 1 Headers aren't repeating.. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the Header repeat on the Group rather than the table. The table paging got a little funky when Microsoft added Tablixs and they've never addressed the issue ("Works as designed").

There's another RepeatOnNewPage property that should be set on the GROUP in the groups Advanced Mode settings.

To get to the properties, select the table, click on the down carat to the right on the Column Groups and click on Advanced mode. Then Select the first header row in the Row Groups to bring up the properties and set the RepeatOnNewPage to True.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I did try the Column "RepeatOnNewPage = True" for each Static member in the group. However, it tells me "All Tablix Member elements in a TablixColumnHierarchy must have the RepeatOnNewPage property set to false"

Comment: @user16909854 - you'll want to set that on the ROW grouping, not the Column as your error indicates (TablixColumnHierarchy).

Comment: I have set the row grouping on, But the header of tablix1 is not repeating when the embedded tablix2 goes to the 2nd page.  (On my single reports where I can use a parameter to pull what I need from 3 tables the header works fine with row grouping)

Comment: I moved the data I want to repeat into the page header, and using a hidden txtbox to show the data in the pageHeader.. Which is a big work around and I am not sure how that will work if the hidden field is not on the 3rd page (or in my case if the 3rd embedded tablix wraps into a 3rd page by itself)

Comment: I've logged into Stack Overflow for the first time in years to say THANKS!  I think this is one of the very few posts that actually shows where these options are now hidden.  Really appreciate it.